# udev rule file works in Debian but not in RHEL8

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, udev

I'm connecting a USB camera to a computer previously running Debian 9 and now RHEL8. I placed a rule file (`50-blackfly.rules`) in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` setting the camera to be owned by a non-root user.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4000", OWNER="camera", GROUP="camera", MODE="0660"
```

In Debian it worked fine, but in RHEL8 the camera is always owned by root:root on reboot. Every time I have to manually run commands:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo udevadm trigger --type=devices --action=change
```

How can I configure the system to get the rule loaded automatically on reboot?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your rule look like and how is the file named?

Comment: cat /etc/udev/rules.d/50-blackfly.rules

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4000", OWNER="camera", GROUP="camera", MODE="0660"

Comment: Sorry. Haven't figured out how to put in a new line yet.

Comment: In the comments you don't -- edit the useful information into the main post instead. Do you have any other rules files for this device, e.g. does `udevadm test /sys/class/video/...` show correct results? And... is your /etc on some sort of NFS or overlayfs?

Comment: I see. Put it in the original post. This is the only rules file for this device. The rule is currently reloaded (manually) but there's no `/sys/class/video/` directory. `/etc` is local.